# How to abstract code which calls various other code

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I’m doing a bunch of projects in CLion, each of which has two pieces of code: `Solution` and `TestConductor`. The `Solution` is the solution to a code kata, and the `TestConductor` uses Catch2 to run the tests (which are stored in `input_n.txt` and `output_n.txt` files). `TestConductor` has to call `Solution`, of course. `Solution` changes for each project (representing a different kata), but `TestConductor` only changes in that it needs to know what the `input.txt` and `output.txt` files are called (their names can vary slightly), and how to call `Solution` (whose name is different for different katas, like it could be called `PermutationFinder` or `PairSorter` or whatever).

I’ve basically been copy-pasting the TestConductor code into each of my projects, which seems smelly to me. What would be the philosophically correct way to work with this? Make TestConductor into a library of some kind? (Still learning how to make and use those.)

TestConductor code is [here](http://pastie.org/p/6QO2fZcbqVhc8ANFgfnOV8) if you want some concreteness. (45 lines)

I guess more generally, what do you do when the code which you want to abstract, and reuse over multiple projects, isn’t called by the code which changes, but rather calls it?

I'm gather this is a rather common situation that has a simple solution. Sorry if this is a repeat question; I didn't know what search terms I could use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make `TestConductor` generic in terms of its Solution class, simply change the class declaration like so:

```
template <class Solution>
class TestConductor { ... };
```

The declaration can then go into a header file that you can include across projects.

In each project you can then supply your testcase as:

```
TEST_CASE() {
    TestConductor<PermutationFinder> testMaker;
    for (int test_number = 1; test_number <= 5; test_number++) {
        string solution = testMaker.get_solution(test_number);
        string test_solution = testMaker.get_test_solution(test_number);
        REQUIRE(solution == test_solution);
        testMaker.reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! A couple picky questions: 1. TestConductor needs to know not only the name of the class, but the name of the method that finds the solution, like `PermutationFinder::find_permutation`. I could just make the method have the same name for all Solution classes, but then I sacrifice the expressiveness of the method name. Is there an alternative? 2. TestConductor needs to know how the input/output files are named for the particular project.  Would you suggest making those parameters of the constructor of TestConductor, or is there a simpler way?

Comment: For 1 you could give TestConductor a pure virtual method `Solution solve(ifstream& in)` OR pass a lambda to the constructor (`TestConductor<PermutationFinder> testMaker([](ifstream &ifs) { return PermutationFinder(ifs).find_permutation(); })` .

Comment: Ah, so in your first suggestion, in each project, I would write a small child class of `TestConductor` and then implement that `solve` function, then use that child class instead for my testing?

Comment: For example, yes.